# Apply a function on multiple columns in each row

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is the data frame I have. Column 2 is the days to expiration of the nearest contract, column 3 is the days to expiration of the next nearest contract. I'm trying to create a vector that gives me the percentage of column 2 needed to give me a weighted average days to expiration of 28 days for each row.

```
   Date        DaysXone       DaysXtwo
1 2006-01-03       15        43 days
2 2006-01-04       14        42 days
3 2006-01-05       13        41 days
4 2006-01-06       12        40 days
5 2006-01-09        9        37 days
6 2006-01-10        8        36 days
```

I've tried:

```
 f <- function(x){
 DF$DaysXone*(x) + (DF$DaysXtwo*(1-(x)) -28}
```

and then I've tried a few things with uniroot(), but now I'm stuck

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question. Could you provide an example of the expected output for one of the rows?

Comment: Yes, from the first row the answer I want is  .5357, The solution for 15x + 43(1-x) -28 = 0. I would like to do that for every row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or go with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(DaysXone = c(15,14,13,12,9,8), DaysXtwo = c(43, 42,41,40, 37,36))
setDT(df)[,Perc := (28-DaysXtwo)/(DaysXone - DaysXtwo),]

   DaysXone DaysXtwo      Perc
1:       15       43 0.5357143
2:       14       42 0.5000000
3:       13       41 0.4642857
4:       12       40 0.4285714
5:        9       37 0.3214286
6:        8       36 0.2857143
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this should do:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, "date", function(i) {res = (-i$DaysXtwo + 28) / (i$DaysXone - i$DaysXtwo)})
```

> ```
>     date        V1
>  1 2006-01-03 0.5357143
>  2 2006-01-04 0.5000000
>  3 2006-01-05 0.4642857
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(DaysXone = c(15,14,13,12,9,8), DaysXtwo = c(43, 42,41,40, 37,36))

perc_function = function(x,y) {
    out = (28-y)/(x-y)
    return(out)
}

df = cbind(df, perc = mapply(perc_function, df$DaysXone, df$DaysXtwo))
```